# Java swing JPanel and JScrollPane not displaying

Tags: java, swing

When I run the program, the JPanel is not visible. It works without the JScrollPane though. This is driving me crazy! Before, I had it using a Canvas and a ScrollPane. Note that FlowchartPanel extends JPanel.

```
public class Window extends JFrame{

private FlowchartPanel panel;                       // contains all the main graphics
private JScrollPane scrollpane;                     // contains panel
private int canvasWidth, canvasHeight;              // the width and height of the canvas object in pixels
private Flowchart flowchart;                        // the flowchart object

public Window(Flowchart flowchart) {
    super();
    canvasWidth = 900;
    canvasHeight = 700;
    this.flowchart = flowchart;
    flowchart.setWidth(canvasWidth);
    flowchart.setHeight(canvasHeight);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel = new FlowchartPanel(flowchart);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    scrollpane.add(panel);
    add(scrollpane);
    //add(panel);
    pack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't add components directly to a `JScrollPane`.

The component needs to be added to the `JViewPort` of the `JScrollPane`

The easiest way to do this is to use:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panel );
```

Another way is to replace (add) the component in the viewport is to use:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( panel );
```

> panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));

Don't set the preferred size of a component. Every Swing component is responsible for determining its own preferred size. Instead override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom panel to return the size. This way as the custom painting changes, you can dynamically change the preferred size as required.